# Java input/output file coding issue

Tags: java, file, input, io, output

Hi I am trying to make a code that will pull up  a user input file and then copy that file into a new file that I created in all uppercase letters. I have no clue why this isn't working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class playAround {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("Uppercase.txt");

    Scanner check = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the filename you would like to be formatted into UPPERCASE");
    String filename = check.nextLine();

    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    while(inputFile.hasNext()){

    String write = inputFile.nextLine();
    outputFile.println(write.toUpperCase());

    }

    inputFile.close();
    outputFile.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: make sure that when you input the file path that you are inputting the entire file path (C:\Users...) or that the file is in the correct location relative to your classpath

Comment: In what way is the program not working? It seems like it writes to the file fine, it just doesn't convert to uppercase.

Comment: Enter the filename you would like to be formatted into UPPERCASE
User input - crazy.txt

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: crazy.txt (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
 at hw7.HW7.main(HW7.java:14)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it is writes the original file to `Uppercase.txt` without converting to uppercase. Change

```
String write = inputFile.nextLine();
```

to

```
String write = inputFile.nextLine().toUpperCase();
```